# Power consumption of Ram and Hard disk

Tags: power, energy

I need to measure the power consumption of the ram and hard disk. Is there any way to measure the voltage and Ampere usage of a Hard-drive, while reading a file?

Comment: Please add the platform (x86, ARM, etc) and OS (like Windows 10, MacOS Catalina etc)  that you are looking for the software. The answer heavily depends on the hardware. HWINFO is a very good tool on Windows, but whether to trust the values provided by sensors or not, is your call. I remember getting sensible reading wit X299 and some higher-grade Corsair RAM. Hard disk usually report closer to truth via S.M.A.R.T. interface, HWINFO reads them too. Beware you'll see a lot of nonsense figures, too (some temp sensors reporting -15⁰C etc), so it's a bit of a workup to find what to trust.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any practical way. You would have to break the relevant circuit on the main board to determine current draw of the part.

Also remember that modern boards have multiple layers and you may not be able to determine the current path. This is not feasible.

Why do you need this? For most of us, the RAM and Drives work properly in the system for which they are designed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to measure would be to apply an digital sampling oscilloscope. If you use an ordinary multimeter, you will get average currents.

```
powersupply -------
                  |-------------------------------------ch. 1 of the scope
                  |
                 +-+
                 | |
                 | | 0.1 ohm
                 | |
                 +-+
                  |--------------------------------------ch.2 of the scope
                  |
             +-----------+
             | hard drive|
             +-----------+
                  | 
ground----------------------------------------------------ground of scope
```

The tension drop over the resistor will give you the current. Note that this is for a hard drive with a single power supply. In the waveform, you should be able to determine when a read occurs.

The main point is, that it is not possible in a normal PC or laptop to just read some registers or `/proc` value; you must take up the soldering iron.

Comment: there are multiple capacitors on the main board; your suggestion would only show the integrated (average) current.

Comment: With the two channels of the scope, you will get not just a single value, but also the waveform of both tension and current. I explicitly used a digital scope and not a multimeter.